# Can Servlet based login be configured the same as JAAS? Can a custom CallbackHandler be used?

Tags: security, jakarta-ee, wildfly, servlet-3.0, jaas

I'm migrating an old JEE5/ servlet 2.4 application to JEE 7/servlet 3.1.  The app will be running on Jboss EAP7 / Wildfly 10.

At the moment, the app is designed/configured to use JAAS.  It has a custom LoginModule which is configured in the standalone.xml file under the authentication/login-module section.

```
            <security-domain name="customWeb" cache-type="default">
                <authentication>
                    <login-module code="security.jboss.CustomLoginModule" flag="required">
                        <module-option name="unauthenticatedIdentity" value="nobody"/>
                    </login-module>
                </authentication>
            </security-domain>
```

My servlet context (web.xml) is configured to use form-based-authentication:

```
   <login-config>
      <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
      <form-login-config>
         <form-login-page>/login.do</form-login-page>
         <form-error-page>/login.do?error=true</form-error-page>
      </form-login-config>
   </login-config>
```

In my login action code, I can trigger it with

```
LoginContext lc = new LoginContext("module", new MyCallbackHandler( arg0, arg1, arg2 ));
lc.login();
```

In my CustomLoginModule, I can specify custom callbacks that my handler knows/understands  how to process.

But Servlet 3 spec has introduced a new method [request.login (username, password)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#login-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-).  If I try to call `request.login( usr, pwd)`, I see that Wildfly ends up calling my CustomLoginModule, but without my custom CallbackHandler.

Is there a way to use this method instead / as well?  How do I configure Wildfly such that I can still pass a custom CallbackHandler when using the servlet login method?  Is it even feasible?

Comment: There's always the alternative of using [JASPIC](http://arjan-tijms.omnifaces.org/2012/11/implementing-container-authentication.html). A [`ServerAuthModule`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/security/auth/message/module/ServerAuthModule.html) can do whatever it pleases, including delegating to a JAAS `LoginModule` using a custom `Configuration`, `LoginContext`, `CallbackHandler`, and whatnot -- and most importantly without having to rely on any vendor-specific "black magic".